# Sailfish OS - change page after dialog accepted

Tags: qt, qml, meego, meego-harmattan, sailfish-os

I have a page that displays information about an object in my database. On this page, I have the possibility of deleting that object by calling a dialog. 
When the user accept the dialog, the object is removed, but by default after accepting the dialog the page displayed is still the one regarding the removed object.

So I want to remove all the pages and move the user to the main page, as if the app is just launched.

I've tried several ways but I can't solve this. 
If I use a pop I get

```
 Warning: cannot pop while transition is in progress
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `acceptDestination` to your main page and `acceptDestinationAction: PageStackAction.Pop`. This will pop all pages above the main page when the dialog is accepted.

https://sailfishos.org/sailfish-silica/qml-sailfishsilica-dialog.html